How to create new branches from previous commits (using git bash)?
I made 6 commits on the master(main) branch, and I added a new branch which starts from the 2nd commit of master branch. But that was yesterday's work. Today, I want to make another brand new branch which starts from the 3rd commit of the master branch. Please tell me how to do that.
I was making commits as usual on master branch....and in that way I made a total of 6 commits in that branch. And, in advance, I already created a new branch from the 2nd commit of master branch, right? In that branch, I made 4 commits. So I wish to create another branch which starts from the 3rd commit of the master branch. But in order to do so, I was unable to get back to the previous commits, because, I Don't know how to do that! Please let me know, how to achieve what I want, by telling me the necessary git commands/important steps.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch

Or perhaps better, https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+branch+old+commit

You can view the commits that you have via
git log

You will see a list of commits and each of those commits has a hash (alphanumeric character string). So, you will need to check out that hash via
git checkout <thehash>

create the branch
git branch <branchname>

and check out the new branch:
git checkout <branchname>

You can push such a branch to the origin (remote) via
git push -u origin <branchname>

